# Rails 4 Simple Model Caching With Redis

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, caching, model, redis

I am new to Redis and Rails caching, and would like to perform simple model caching. I have just read these 2 articles :

http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-model-caching-redis/

http://www.victorareba.com/tutorials/speed-your-rails-app-with-model-caching-using-redis

Since Redis model caching consists in storing JSON strings in redis and retrieving them with code like

```
def fetch_snippets
  snippets =  $redis.get("snippets")
  if snippets.nil?
    snippets = Snippet.all.to_json
    $redis.set("snippets", snippets)
  end
  @snippets = JSON.load snippets
end
```

I don't understand what is the need of using

```
gem 'redis-rails'
gem 'redis-rack-cache'
```

I don't see where the cache store or other caching mechanisms are at use in that kind of examples, since they consist only in reading/writing to Redis.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What are the gems redis-rails and redis race-cache used for in that kind of situations? I don't understand what's their purpose here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is what I have in my Gemfile

```
gem 'redis'
gem 'readthis'
gem 'hiredis'
gem 'redis-browser'
```

readthis - recently implemented nice feature to not crash Rails when Redis is down [Disable Rails caching if Redis is down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33457765/disable-rails-caching-if-redis-is-down).  And it supports advanced Redis data types (not just strings as redis-rails).

hiredis - is a little faster

redis-browser - allows me to see what is actually cached (easier than cli).

Here is my application.rb

```
config.cache_store = :readthis_store, { expires_in: 1.hour.to_i, namespace: 'foobar', redis: { host: config.redis_host, port: 6379, db: 0 }, driver: :hiredis }
```

Then in my models I do:

```
def my_method_name
  Rails.cache.fetch("#{cache_key}/#{__method__}", expires_in: 1.hour) do
    # put my code here
  end
end
```

I used https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler to see which queries were firing lots of DB request and determined what I should cache.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet you posted isn't really clever. It assumes that the entire snippet collection is never updated locally, as it doesn't set any expiration for the content that is stored into Redis.

As for the gems, you don't need them at all if your goal is the example you posted.

The `redis-rails` is likely a plugin to connect to Redis in Rails. However, connecting to Redis is as easy as creating an initializer file and opening a new connection to Redis with the correct Redis URL using the Ruby Redis gem.

The second gem seems to add a Redis-based storage for [Rack cache](https://rubygems.org/gems/rack-cache). If you don't know what it is, it's probably better if you don't use it at all.

Comment: I agree, this is very simplistic. I added an after_save callback in the model to clear the cache whenever new objects are created, especially because in my case the model objects do not change very often and are only changed/created by an admin. As you say, having the redis initializer, I did not get why use redis-rails, so thanks for specifying that. But redis-rails README also includes config cache_store to :redis_store. Is the only purpose of that line the ability to make that the default cache and call Rails.cache instead of a redis global var for instance?